# The method '*' was called on null - Flutter

Tags: flutter, exception, layout

I used the plugin sizer.
When I set the height to 20.0.h,
It gives the following error:
The method '*' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: *(20.0)

Comment: could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have initialized the sizer correctly and use it within Layout and OrientationBuilder

```
return LayoutBuilder(                          
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return OrientationBuilder(                 
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        SizerUtil().init(constraints, orientation);  
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'INITIALIZE!',
          home: ...,
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```